# How to Ensure Unique Records

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

In an SQLite database, I have a table called `people` that has columns `prefix`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, and `suffix`. The full name is the concatenation of all of these columns, separated by spaces. Is there any way to create a constraint that forces the *full name* to be unique (i.e., no two rows can have the same five values for `prefix`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, and `suffix`)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Just put a unique constraint/index on all five columns:

```
create unique index unq_people_name on people(prefix, first_name, middle_name, last_name, suffix);
```

You do realize, of course, that some people do have identical names.